# Pandas.read_excel: Accessing the home directory

Tags: python, pandas, path

**[Solution Found]**

I have encountered some unexpected behavior when trying to access my home directory using `pandas.read_excel`.

The file I want to access can be found at

```
/users/isys/orsheridanmeth
```

which is where `cd ~/` takes me to. The file I would like to access is

```
'~/workspace/data/example.xlsx'
```

The following works to read in the excel file (using `import pandas as pd`):

```
df = pd.read_excel('workspace/data/example_.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

whereas

```
df = pd.read_excel('~/workspace/data/example.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

gives me the following error:

```
df = pd.read_excel('~/workspace/data/example.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/is/ahlpypi/egg_cache/i/ipython-3.2.0_1_ahl1-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-397-4412a9e7c128>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel('~/workspace/data/example.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
  File "/users/is/ahlpypi/egg_cache/p/pandas-0.16.2_ahl1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/excel.py", line 151, in read_excel
    return ExcelFile(io, engine=engine).parse(sheetname=sheetname, **kwds)
  File "/users/is/ahlpypi/egg_cache/p/pandas-0.16.2_ahl1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/io/excel.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "/users/is/ahlpypi/egg_cache/x/xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/xlrd/__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/workspace/data/example.xlsx'
```

**pandas.read_csv** however worked when I used `pd.read_csv('~/workspace/data/example.csv')`.

I would like to continue to use this relative paths to files. Any explanation why this doesn't work with `pandas.read_excel`?

**Using `xlrd`**

when using `xlrd` I get a similar error:

```
import xlrd
xl = xlrd.open_workbook('~/workspace/data/example.xlsx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/is/ahlpypi/egg_cache/i/ipython-3.2.0_1_ahl1-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-403-90af31feff4b>", line 1, in <module>
    xl = xlrd.open_workbook('~/workspace/data/example.xlsx')
  File "/users/is/ahlpypi/egg_cache/x/xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/xlrd/__init__.py", line 394, in open_workbook
    f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/workspace/data/example.xlsx'
```

**[SOLUTION]**

```
from os.path import expanduser as ospath
df = pd.read_excel(ospath('~/workspace/data/example.xlsx'), 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: I suspect that as `read_excel` is using some third party module, `xlrd` in this case that it can't handle this, you could try using `xlrd` module directly to see if the error also happens with that module

Comment: I seem to get the same error when using `xlrd'.

Comment: I think in this case you'll have to expand `~` prior to passing it to `read_excel`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe `~` is expanded by the shell - in which case your code is literally trying to open a path starting with `~`. Oddly enough this doesn't work. :-)

Try running the path through `os.path.expanduser()` first - that should work to expand the `~` variable to the real value.

You may also want to look into `os.path.expandvars()`.

Hope that helps