# Loading data in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, loading

I am trying to load excel sheets in jupyter notebook using pandas but it is showing error " file doesn't exist". But the file exists in the current working directory. Why the error is coming?

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476733/pandas-read-excel-accessing-the-home-directory

Comment: It would help if you provided the code you tried with